# Is there a way I can copy files from an old react project to start a new one without having to waste bandwidth and rerun create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

How can I start a new react project without having to re-run the *npx create-react-app* cmd and wasting bandwidth? How can I just copy the files from the old project?

I tried copying the files from the old project but got an error

```
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at handleParseError (D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:434:10)
    at D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:466:5
    at D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:327:12
    at D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:418:10
    at D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:293:13
    at D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at D:\Developer Tools\ZTM applied\react\robofriends\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Comment: What command did you run to get that error? Also, what files did you copy?

Comment: I tried running npm start

Comment: Actually I just found this solution where I change this line in package.json **"start": "react-scripts start",** in _scripts_ to **"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",**